# Extracting URLs of certain pattern from text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have following URLs that needs to be fetched from page. [This](https://regex101.com/r/pudx92/1) is the attempt I made but it is skipping part of string if it has `=`. Different kinds of URLs given below:

> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=2~2586506573108327708~9SpSI_aPBiryk3VIKwmkjN-FD4jkS5GoDobsBCN6pRnZOhBsmrEOgT8vg5KciKjOmt25k3kEDZ00r7f48bIsRPSZWTHJbSCpS815cCNyQrsobBzLZlao8ww-rWwg0lLDIb10gJ3vWUl3zLIAQi5vBGLglJKXcSEg7wCXZUEm5aVHCQiGChz5f8oeiBtPXAV_A9XQ7xU5HUzyzTzyEMJICw==&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=7~502085760588479881~-8dtDO_8-jpTBfqALerDcDLkIIRWnom8BG9WdtIVgqGTlRDn37waNvbaM_VHLrcntsGabZPzMiFlNxsrmqx4VpCZrtJmjyCcOBr9AY1B2GxnTlh3ngYfIYbhnDi-W6Hpb8V77OSS-WviMKsgF87gcWvjGzEd02a7Q_3XQ2FvdZ2rvwDlwG4izypuO7Ob63Gh&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=5~6917684668841666406~70K0Ijfg4OhPeKlzLP8aQV4JjBq9WuXnpC3enGYXfyWj5-28RyHRnjGRJypZBi0knr3io-9UdjdlOWuLqisI_pkZ0hQzFA5bhlRkX7siC6uMUA6A_MntiLDNGTrKN47TvrAxRd_JpQQUprReVHYwSdUEQvVUtpKn1_Ku5WG_zyWe_0Sd7FLftU1ti6pYf_tfMyNiDalQzyrPDQ35sAXcYIDyhSYI08uZCmTq5vrjSNkQChnMSW73MKri42rVM3JVP8j5LfCf3Zrws54M8KkFRnvfsyYeYd-hATgywsv9i2rtU3A-KPP6lSrL6jqbkAXVTezFRYV00ZNUhvX8NrL8Ew==&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=2~3180584448022130058~v_d5bPfBCJINSmPxaUaByy3S5n5h5UbQ53k5QKhqYbz7KXeHku95HjcqE2MnU18rRhcdnBghBW90u-GS3tqZc5FBGt6Z9-mNBnr6RPTiAlIdlG9vO8QDW7e7vMS5H2Yue3sRQ5ANzNKGoAXe3Z5GpC1HWW9DA55OGRkLRsGdNRbN3VkqiVpObCQNGHyDYhfrh_WF8uPpAb5WE2s9sDvrSVDkUfuvHclAarXoua9OYsDQtYaDGxaquDkZrIO-VEYgjv-CPKwCkOQyOVqdq--QQ-GQNvi8vHk05uoiU6-9Kg4=&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=5~7279828915011575224~9KhHzCPV9FXMYfGNPF7W0MNL_4Ljv3YFdCr_JVtQN0GhUhD7ohGtUTYCzRJvS4sI6uyoM3TTrNmHaMsidk_BiN9qXRKpdEhJHGgfHHLzU1vtAXejIwnQUxB5Oexjkt74WeBnEfVSrxVfvhRM3LoB076SYiK5x92bA8WqJg62YtsUWV7vqtsCpvKyn9ssF7nnjlTmUqIWpBkqC9ZtcfN7-A==&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=7~502085760588479881~-8dtDO_8-jpTBfqALerDcDLkIIRWnom8BG9WdtIVgqGTlRDn37waNvbaM_VHLrcntsGabZPzMiFlNxsrmqx4VpCZrtJmjyCcOBr9AY1B2GxnTlh3ngYfIYbhnDi-W6Hpb8V77OSS-WviMKsgF87gcWvjGzEd02a7Q_3XQ2FvdZ2rvwDlwG4izypuO7Ob63Gh&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=3~4781276045400603393~duZpRpWJA0naDjmpXNSp__ILjEXoOrwiv9SVBUjldBK4ebRdYWlzxwRudeyHrXoCC-XM_xEKr475_ViwwaHlnqFgEqteM3N6bDAgOxWEc8Y5Klh5d3Ivb_6qG6VsfMmp8oaT3nLnuALjX8vfqBN72WsNlwWeGMR3lOTuQnHgbl2betlejT6KsRx7ycVv71mxe8BP7oDIdI29Baetjlv1YA==&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=6~7112793196313446100~IVBMr0jpuDOH9HKclY47FtAJQXrgqOsD6P7mbOwJOcbDWAbviVmEg1HZScYqiKL5svd6BGA7jm22V6uEvquNb_-cZEyfDIFGbNxF3WNTwXcGX13GWcVi6tg7Acgdw8SHEEvhJzw1U01lvMS-Ptks6eeWj0cDdM_Al9hS5WkUA4ZR7rQK5CU9Uovn9WWF5I-6Ot0zcXZKaJMNIndiPYdIq0rpcpehlB8k&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1
>
> AjaxRender.htm?encparams=10~1438958542856547329~OUrqnIrSPt0QON_7Q12RhcKfwyc22cFvE0xIIobEoUIFu91yWu5SK_jSW59wazXcfcxjpZnQ9YTWAH5kxu8H2B-lu2vO9J47cqg9ThA6AvDFRhj-6moF1_6ymrCKqhbcJdQddN24hShw9IwJOs2uDYJ2bECVJlnoraak4PGtBLHV4TnoVy9eZJxVPNB3XbIumIivk84XZyg=&rwebid=8347449&rhost=1

The issue I am facing that string before `&rwebid` gets `-` or `=` occasionally (base 64?) which breaks thing.

**Updated**
https://regex101.com/r/pudx92/2

Comment: Try replacing `\d+~\d+~\w+-\w+-\w+` with `[^"]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you elaborate?

Comment: Someone below already "is elaborating".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just stop on string delimiter `"` ?

```
AjaxRender[.]htm[?]encparams=[^\"]*
```

Comment: The text exists between other code. Will it not pull everything else?

Comment: The semantics of `[^"]*` is match the longest sequence of any characters other than `"`. Assuming every of your url you care about is a enclosed in `"` you should be fine.